# iTextSharp PDFForm Radio Button format change

Tags: itext

We have a library of PDF forms which we're filling with variable content in text, check box and radio button form fields.  Since the form is a template, we use the PDFStamper to perform the form fills. Everything is filling and checking appropriately.  The problem we have is that the Radio Button controls are set up (in the form) to display a check mark and not the conventional dot within a circle.  When filling the form manually with Acrobat reader, the buttons appear as check boxes however; after filling with iText PDFStamper, the resulting PDF radio buttons revert to their conventional style (dot within a circle).

Is this a bug or is it the intended functionality? Is there a work around.  We are currently on V5.5.8.  I know in previous version(s) the formatting was maintained.

Thanks for any help .

Comment: Are you sure that your question isn'ta duplicate of [this question](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/why-does-itext-enter-cross-symbol-when-checktype-style-check-mark)? The appearance of a radio button is usually stored inside the PDF and iText respects that appearance. If you want an answer to this question, you'll have to share the form so that we can inspect it.

Comment: That is kind of what happens.  When the form fields are flattened, the "check" style radio buttons revert to the conventional style - dot within a circle.  If the form fields are not flattened, the "check" style is maintained.  Is this the normal behavior?  If so, me may have to live with this outcome.  I've verified that all of the radio buttons on the form are of type "check".